Meaning of V + ての + noun
In かつて神だった獣たちへ volume 5 I found these sentences, speaking about bayonets:

もちろん接近しなくては使いようもなく、ライフルの登場は歩兵同士が肉薄しての銃撃と突撃による戦術、つまり銃剣を過去の物にするはずだった


内戦末期、戦場に登場した回転式機関砲は十分な威力と連射速度を持っていたため、肉薄しての突撃を押さえ込まれ無力だった

I found that VてのN means that the noun is a necessary condition for the verb to be possible (here, here and here), but I'm not sure how should I read those sentences with that meaning: the first sounds like:

もちろん接近しなくては使いようもなく、ライフルの登場は歩兵同士が肉薄: naturally, they couldn't be used without approaching [the enemy], and speaking of the appearance of rifles the infantry approached the enemy


銃撃と突撃による戦術、つまり銃剣を過去の物にするはずだった: strategies by attacking and charging, in other words bayonets should have been made a thing of the past.

If VてのN means "Because N, then V"... because there were strategies using attacking and charging, infantry approached the enemy, in other words bayonets should have been made a thing of the past? It doesn't really sound right.
From the contest I guess that rifles should have made bayonets (or maybe melee weapons) a thing of the past, because they made harder to approach the enemy, which is a necessary condition to use bayonets; but I don't understand how that sentence works in its entirety.
Similar issue with the second sentence:

内戦末期、戦場に登場した回転式機関砲は十分な威力と連射速度を持っていたため、肉薄しての突撃を押さえ込まれ無力だった

Which sounds something like "In the last period of the civil war, since on the battlefield rotating machineguns appeared with enough firepower and rate of fire" and something about being powerless to contain attacks from the enemy, but again I can't really understand the sentence as a whole (also because rotating machineguns sound like something able to contain an advancing enemy, so I'm guessing I'm missing something).

cf. https://mainichi-nonbiri.com/grammar/n2-teno/

So according to meaning 2 the first sentence would mean something like "tactics where infantry shoots and charge after closing in on the enemy"?

I think a good approximation would be: VてのN ~ N with V
Not very good translation but you can get a rough idea by this.
肉薄しての銃撃: shooting with getting close ~ shooting at close range
ギターを抱えての移動: moving with a guitar
I guess the correct second sentence is

内戦末期、戦場に登場した回転式機関砲は十分な威力と連射速度を持っていたなかったため、肉薄しての突撃をに押さえ込まれ無力だった

close combat >  rotary machine gun (Gatling cannon?)
or

内戦末期、戦場に登場した回転式機関砲は十分な威力と連射速度を持っていたため、肉薄しての突撃には押さえ込まれ無力だった

close combat <  rotary machine gun
depending on the context. Otherwise, the original one doesn't make sense to me.

Maybe it's a typo in the manga, I checked and the text is as I wrote here.

The original text may not be well-written, but I interpreted it as "戦場に登場した(敵の)回転式機関砲は十分な威力と連射速度を持っていたため、(我々の銃剣は)肉薄しての突撃を押さえ込まれ無力だった". Perhaps rifles were hardly better than bayonets but machines guns were better than bayonets.
